# .htaccess issue with no access to Apache

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, laravel

As stated above, we've been tasked with a project but have been told that it must be uploaded to the University servers and must also use the University databases (Absolutely ridiculous).

I started developing the app using the framework: Laravel.
Unfortunately, I've hit a snag in that I believe the University Apache servers are causing issues but I have no way of proving this as I'm still new to all of this rewrite stuff.

I know for sure that Apache Rewrite is enabled.

My university html file system directory is the following:

```
/home/nt***/public_html/
```

To access these files, we have to navigate to (I've cut the actual address):

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://universitywebsite.ac.uk/~nt***/public/index.php
```

Now, for whatever reason, going to the address: http://universitywebsite.ac.uk/~nt***/public/ automatically redirects me to: http://universitywebsite.ac.uk/public
Is this caused by their apache settings? If so, is there a way around it?

Nevertheless, I have it somewhat working with the following .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ http://universitywebsite.ac.uk/~nt***/public/index.php/$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://universitywebsite.ac.uk/~nt***/public/index.php [L]
```

which works for everything but the base http://universitywebsite.ac.uk/~nt***/public/ as this still redirects me. And the request uri is as follows: REQUEST_URI    /~nt****/user/login.
Which obviously doesn't work. as that is not the correct file system directory.

I'm so confused! Sorry for my lack of knowledge, if I can help with anything else, please let me know.

Comment: what's the first rule supposed to do?

Comment: Honestly? I have no clue. I basically just copied the laravel one and played around a little

Comment: have you tried removing it?

Comment: Honestly, it's difficult to even explain what it's currently doing: .
Without a .htaccess file at all, the following works: http://universitywebsite.ac.uk/~nt***/public/index.php/user/login but is obviously not ideal and unfortunately, all links point to the wrong directory: https://universitywebsite.ac.uk/public/css/font-awesome.min.css

Comment: Ask to the web master of your university, or move to other university if you cannot bear about management of university's web.

Comment: Not possible unfortunately, in true student fashion, the work is due in the next 8 hours

Answer (score 0):

Your 2nd rules should not have `http://` in target URI for internal rewrite. Try this as 2nd rule:

```
# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . /~nt***/public/index.php [L]
```